# Azure Data Studio - Prevent update without where clause

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-studio

Is there any extension that would prevent executing an update query without the where clause?

Comment: I'm not aware of one but I think it's a great idea!

Comment: for Management Studio I've created one, back in the day...... but for Azure I didn't had the chance :(